# POST request not uploading file to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I've been stuck with this problem for 3 days. I'm using React.js on the frontend with `axios` and want to upload the file to the server. There is an API endpoint which is a post endpoint something like this.

```
POST- https://88.66.123.122:20000/b1s/v1/Attachments2
```

This endpoint basically uploads the files to the server file system with the successful response that has `201` status. The response is successfully fine when I test the endpoint with the Desktop client `Postman` and the code snippet generated by this tool is this.

[image: Postman Snippet]

But I want to achieve this thing in browser UI. So I'm using React.js for this.

This endpoint also needs an authorization cookie in the request header to make sure the user is authenticated. So In the UI, I created a login button that basically sends a post request with a hardcoded credentials to the `login` endpoint and giving me a successful response with a session id.

I'm saving the session id in the browser as a cookie for the upload file but when I'm sending the cookie with the request, I'm getting the following response in the browser

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

and the response I'm getting back with the following JSON.

```
POST https://88.66.123.122:20000/b1s/v1/Attachments2 [401 (Unauthorized)]

{
   "error" : {
      "code" : 301,
      "message" : {
         "lang" : "en-us",
         "value" : "Invalid session."
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know How I can solve this problem? You can see the [**GIF**](https://s6.gifyu.com/images/sample.gif).

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const URL_LOGIN = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}Login`;
const COMPANY_DB = process.env.REACT_APP_DB;
const URL_ATTACHMENT = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}Attachments2`;
const CREDENTIALS = {
  UserName: process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME,
  Password: process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD,
  CompanyDB: COMPANY_DB
};


function App() {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = React.useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null);

  function onClick() {
    setIsLogin(true);
    axios
      .post(URL_LOGIN, CREDENTIALS)
      .then(function (response) {
        setIsLogin(false);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        setIsLogin(false);
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  // onUpload
  function handleUpload(event) {
    console.log('File set', event.target.files[0]);
    setSelected(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  function uploadSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', selected, selected?.name);

    axios
      .post(URL_ATTACHMENT, formData)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('response', response);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={onClick} disabled={isLogin}>
          Login Create Cookie
        </button>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={handleUpload} />
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={uploadSubmit}>
          Upload File
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When you send cookies from your browser it adds Http only flag in your Cookie. The HttpOnly cookie flag is a security feature in the browser to prevent displaying of cookies via client-side scripting. The cookies should be set by the server and thebrowser internally manages the sending of cookies with each request. So, you don't need to explicitly set the Cookie header yourself

Comment: When exactly are you getting the _Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"_ error? Is it when `uploadSubmit()` is called?

Comment: @TasosK. When I was setting cookies inside the `uploadSubmit()` axios headers configuration.

Comment: @VenNilson I would expect that cookies to be sent automatically. Can you check how will it behave if you remove this configuration? Also, could you share this code part (axios headers configuration)?

Answer (score 9):

The cookies are managed by the server, not the client. In your case, you are using a cookie with `HttpOnly` flag. The client side scripting will not allow you to read the value of Cookies as it is a security threat.

In your nodejs application, the server must be sending a Cookie in response. The server must be doing something like this:

```js
// nodejs (express)
res.cookie('cookieKey', "value", { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
```

notice the httpOnly flag, this flag prevents the cookie to be used by the client-side scripting.

Once you set the cookie in response to your NodeJs (Express) request, your browser should automatically start sending the Cookie with each of your requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I've to create a node.js script for this. Can you please create o share a snippet of node.js/express? I'm totally a noob in Node.js.

Comment: No, you don't need a node.js script. I have mentiond NodeJs because you've tagged node in your question. Check the response headers of your login endpoint. You will notice a `Set-Cookie` header in your response. Your login endpoint must be setting a Cookie

Comment: yes, you're right the response header has set-cookie key-value pair with something like this `Set-Cookie: B1SESSION=81e82488-d0c1-11eb-8000-000c29cc73a5;HttpOnly;`
`Set-Cookie: CompanyDB=Employee;HttpOnly;`
`Set-Cookie: ROUTEID=.node2; path=/b1s`

Comment: Yes, remove the Cookie header from your axios request, and it should work. The browser will automatically set the Cookie with each request behind the scene.

Comment: Remove both Set Cookie and Get Cookie logic from your client

Comment: I've changed the code and remove the set Cookie and get Cookie from the code and sending the request the response is same `{
   "error" : {
      "code" : 301,
      "message" : {
         "lang" : "en-us",
         "value" : "Invalid session."
      }
   }
}`

Comment: Make sure you login again to refresh the Cookies. Maybe cookies are expired. If you have access to server you can check the request headers as well if Cookies are being passed or not

Comment: also in your Cookie the path is set to `/b1s`. This means your upload endpoint must be in this path.

Comment: You mean the endpoint should be `/b1s` instead of `https://88.66.123.122:20000/b1s/v1/Attachments2`. I've updated the code in my question and removed the cookie logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233953/discussion-between-ven-nilson-and-amir-saleem).

Comment: please see the GIF (https://s6.gifyu.com/images/sample.gif).

Answer (score 0):

If the request is cross-origin be sure to add `withCredentials: true` as a header in the axios request

Answer (score 0):

After successfully getting the cookie/token from the server, pass the token in the header. (depends on how you are securing your API endpoint.)

```
axios
      .post(URL_ATTACHMENT, formData, { headers : { header : token }})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('response', response);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      });
```